# The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#86032):

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I get this error message and have no idea how to fix it:

> Exception caught by widgets library
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#86032):

````
The method 'call' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: call(Instance of 'ChangeNotifierProvider<UserLoggedIn>')```
````

And this is the code that's the cause of this problem:

```dart
void main() {
    runApp(ProviderScope(child:MyApp()));
 }

class MyApp extends StatefulHookWidget {

 @override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>
```

I thought I should change the current flutter version I use because this happened when I updated flutter, but that didn't work.

Comment: Does it happen by making `MyApp` to statelessWidget or statefulWidget?

Comment: Hey Yeasin, my problem still persists. It happens at statefulWidget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may have updated flutter to a version that has null safety.
When this happens, methods cannot be null even if in the previous version of flutter it was ok and ran.
Take a look at these references:
[Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

[Migration](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: Hey Nick, I have migrated my code but the problem still persists.